# What is ViewBag.LoadJQueryOnInit and ViewBag.EnableDevExpressView?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have just employed in a company, i see some code like this on `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
 @if (ViewBag.LoadJQueryOnInit == true || ViewBag.EnableDevExpressView == true)
      {
            <script src="/Content/js/vendor/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
      }
```

i searched about it, but i realy don't understand what does this code means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ViewBag is a dynamic property that takes advantage of the new dynamic features in C# 4.0.

It is basically checking the values of `ViewBag.LoadJQueryOnInit` and `ViewBag.EnableDevExpressView` if they are true then render this script tag which will inclde jquery on the page.

If you go in the action of this view, you will see that these two properties are begin set there on some condition to `true` or `false`.

For Example:

I am setting **ViewBag** in controller action:

```
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Test/
        private static Users _users = new Users();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.LoadJQueryOnInit = true;
            ViewBag.EnableDevExpressView
            return View(m);
        }
}
```

Now in View of this action i will check with if that if one of them is true include jQuery library as they depend on jQuery library:

```
@if (ViewBag.LoadJQueryOnInit == true || ViewBag.EnableDevExpressView == true)
      {
            <script src="/Content/js/vendor/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
      }
```

You can put in it any thing in `ViewBag` and its type will be resolved on runtime by VuewBag, you can put string, int , complex object, what ever you want.

```
`ViewBag.AnyKey' = "SomeValue";
```

You can read more about it in detail:

http://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/viewbag-dynamic-in-asp-net-mvc-3-rc-2

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/476967/WhatplusisplusViewData-cplusViewBagplusandplusTem

http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc-3-applications

Comment: these are self defined you can write any thing ``ViewBag.AnyKey``, you can put in it any thing and its type will be resolved on runtime by VuewBag, you can put ``string``, ``int`` , complex object, what ever you want